# Custom Validator Rules in Laravel Return always message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem that I can't find a solution, in reality 2 problems.

The first problem is the following, I made a custom validation rule to validate the "NIF" (identity used in Portugal), until this point everything is working, the validation rule is working, the problem is the message that is returning, the message is always "The given data was invalid." but "Invalid NIF" should appear.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class NifValidator implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $ignoreFirst = true;
        $nif = trim($value);
        \Log::info("Valida Rules NIF: " . $nif);
        //Verificamos se é numérico e tem comprimento 9
        if (!is_numeric($nif) || strlen($nif) != 9) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $nifSplit = str_split($nif);
            //O primeiro digíto tem de ser 1, 2, 5, 6, 8 ou 9
            //Ou não, se optarmos por ignorar esta "regra"
            if (
                in_array($nifSplit[0], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9])
                ||
                $ignoreFirst
            ) {
                //Calculamos o dígito de controlo
                $checkDigit = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                    $checkDigit += $nifSplit[$i] * (10 - $i - 1);
                }
                $checkDigit = 11 - ($checkDigit % 11);
                //Se der 10 então o dígito de controlo tem de ser 0
                if ($checkDigit >= 10) {
                    $checkDigit = 0;
                }

                //Comparamos com o último dígito
                if ($checkDigit == $nifSplit[8]) {
                    \Log::info("VALIDA NIF  TRUE");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    \Log::info("VALIDA NIF  False");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                \Log::info("VALIDA NIF  false");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public function validate($attribute, $value, $params)
    {
        return $this->passes($attribute, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return ':attribute inválido';
    }
}
```

My AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Environment;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $env = app(Environment::class);

        if ($fqdn = optional($env->hostname())->fqdn) {
            config(['database.default' => 'tenant']);
        }

        // money format
        Str::macro('money', function ($price) {
            return number_format($price, 2, ',', '.');
        });

        \Validator::extend('nifvalidator', '\App\Rules\NifValidator@validate');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Authentication\Register;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Exception;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use \App\Traits\Helpers\ResponseJSON;

    public function create()
    {
        try {
            $payload = request()->all();

            $rules = [
                'nif' => 'required',
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => [
                    'required',
                    'string',
                    'min:8', // must be at least 8 characters in length
                    'regex:/[A-Za-z]/', // must contain at least one uppercase letter
                    'regex:/[0-9]/', // must contain at least one digit
                ],
                'country' => 'required',
            ];

            $messages = [
                'password.regex' => 'A password precisa ter no minimo 1 letra e 1 número',
            ];

            //portugal
            if (176 == $payload['country']) {
                // if (!Cliente::validaNif($payload['nif'])) {
                //     throw new Exception("register.nif_invalid");
                // }
                $rules['nif'] = "nifvalidator";
            }

            $this->validate(request(), $rules, $messages);

            
            return $this->responseJSON([], 'register.register_success');
        } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $validExcept) {
            return $this->responseJSON([], $validExcept->getMessage(), 401);
        } catch (Exception $except) {            
            return $this->responseJSON([], $except->getMessage(), 401);
        }
    }
}
```

The second problem is that if I noticed the controller I did a regex validation in the password field to identify if there is a letter or a number, I also customized the message that would appear in the regex field, but the message that returns is always the same "The given data was invalid.

To be honest, I don't know what to do anymore, everything I found on the internet I tried and it didn't work.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: your nif rule is working fine, but message is not what you have attached to the rule?

Comment: Yes, the message should be: "Invalid NIF" but it always returns: "The given data was invalid"

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct the error is due to not using passes() passes is a function predefined in interface Rule which you have implemented,
So, I guess it should work by changing in the service provider,

```
public function boot(): void
    {
        \Validator::extend('empty_if', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $rule = new \App\Rules\NifValidator();
            return $rule->passes();
        });
        // or you can try though I have not sure of the commented method if it works you can inform me It would be new knowledge for me.
        // \Validator::extend('nifvalidator', '\App\Rules\NifValidator@passes');
    }
```

If it doesn't work you can always add it in the $messages(though it is not what you have asked but just as second option)

```
$messages = [
                'password.regex' => 'A password precisa ter no minimo 1 letra e 1 número',
                'nif.nifvalidator' => ':attribute inválido'
            ];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I did the test you quoted about "passes" but it didn't work, the message that returns is "The given data was invalid.", The second test you quoted I tried, including the second question I had is that the "password.regex" is not returning the custom message I put, but it is returning "The given data was invalid."